# Custom Css PhotoGallery Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, photo-gallery

I can't find in css of my plugin to turn of css grow effect on images when hover , maybe im looking in wrong place . Can someone help me switch this effect off.

Here's my site :
http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/

Thanks for answers
Best Regards
Czajos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I think would be to add this in to your stylesheet:

```css
.bwg_album_thumb_spun1_0:hover {
  transform: scale(1) !important;
}
```

Comment: That work perfect , Thank you so much . Have a nice day .